# FastReport: Groupheader in MasterBand, DetailBand and SubDetailBand

Tags: fastreport

I am using groupheader in 3 tables  using MasterBand, DetailBand and SubdetailBand.

MasterDataBand
  GroupHeader1
  DetailDataBand
   GroupHeader2
   SubDetailBand

With DrillDown enabled, when GroupHeader2 is clicked it also expanding all groupheaders of the same level in another master detail records. Any idea how to expand only the groupheader which is clicked

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug. Fix available on Build : 2.2.5 .